# For two complex numbers $ z_1 , z_2 $ , what does $ \vert \sqrt{7} z_1 + 3 z_2 \vert ^2 + \vert - \sqrt{7} z_2 + 3 z_1 \vert ^2 $ equals

Tags: complex-numbers

I am beginner to complex numbers.
I want to find the value of $ z_1 , z_2 $ , $ \vert \sqrt{7} z_1 + 3 z_2 \vert ^2 + \vert - \sqrt{7} z_2 + 3 z_1 \vert ^2 $ for any two non-zero complex numbers $ z_1 $ , $ z_2 $ .

Simply substituting $ z_1 : a + ib, z_2 : c+ id $ seems very lengthy. I want an appropriate method.

Comment: equals to what?

Comment: This equals: $16(|z_1|^2 + |z_2|^2)$.

Comment: @Rohan Answer is also known to me.. I want the way to solve

Comment: @gimusi $ * $ edited $ * $

Comment: Sorry for this question! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: We know that $$|\sqrt{7}z_1 + 3z_2|^2 = 7|z_1|^2 + 2(3)(\sqrt{7})z_1z_2 + 9|z_2|^2$$

Can you take it from here by also calculating $|-\sqrt{7}z_2 + 3z_1|^2$ and then adding them up?